# Equivalent definition of Differentiability of function of two variable.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I know the definition of Fréchet derivative of function between two normed space.and one can think it is a generalization of our usual definition of derivative of real function.But in a book i [faced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CailI.jpg) (equivalent) definition for real valued function of two variable.so can i have hint how can i show this definition is equivalent to Fréchet derivative :
I dont even know how to start as in definition which i faced they define two error term what can i do from Frechet definition is only 1 error term.so how to get another?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this is the definition of the Frechet derivative for a function $f: X\to Y$ between the normed spaces $X,Y$ at the point $z$.
$$f(z+h)=f(z)+G(h)+g(h),\ g(h)\in o(||h||_X)$$
Where $G(h)$ is a continuous linear operator between $X$ and $Y$. And $g(h)\in o(||h||_X)$ means that when $h\to0$, then $\ \frac{||g(h)||_Y}{||h||_X}\to 0$.
In the case of a function of two variables we have $X=\mathbb{R}^2$, $Y=\mathbb{R}$, the norms are the standard euclidean norm and the absolute value, $z=(x,y)$.

So the Frechet derivative becomes
$$f(x+\delta x, y+\delta y)=f(x, y)+G(\delta x, \delta y)+g(\delta x, \delta y),\ g(\delta x, \delta y)\in o(\sqrt{(\delta x)^2+(\delta y)^2})$$
also note that any linear function $G(\delta x, \delta y)$ in this case has the form
$G(\delta x, \delta y)=A\delta x + B\delta y$.
So the only thing to show is the equivalence between the single error term $g(\delta x, \delta y)\in o(\sqrt{(\delta x)^2+(\delta y)^2})$ and the double term $\delta x\phi(\delta x, \delta y)+\delta y\psi(\delta x, \delta y)$.

**The first direction**, we have the single term $g(\delta x, \delta y)\in o(\sqrt{(\delta x)^2+(\delta y)^2})$. Define also the function
$$\operatorname{sign}(t)=\begin{cases}-1&,\ t<0 \\ 1&,\ t>0 \\ 0&,\ t=0\end{cases}$$
And write $g(\delta x, \delta y)$ as
$$g(\delta x, \delta y)=\delta x\operatorname{sign}(\delta x)\frac{g(\delta x, \delta y)}{|\delta x|+|\delta y|}+\delta y\operatorname{sign}(\delta y)\frac{g(\delta x, \delta y)}{|\delta x|+|\delta y|}$$
So we have
$$\phi(\delta x, \delta y)=\operatorname{sign}(\delta x)\frac{g(\delta x, \delta y)}{|\delta x|+|\delta y|}$$
$$\psi(\delta x, \delta y)=\operatorname{sign}(\delta y)\frac{g(\delta x, \delta y)}{|\delta x|+|\delta y|}$$
And both functions tend to $0$ as $\delta x,\delta y$ tend to zero simultaneously because
$$\bigg|\operatorname{sign}(\delta x)\frac{g(\delta x, \delta y)}{|\delta x|+|\delta y|}\bigg|=\bigg|\operatorname{sign}(\delta y)\frac{g(\delta x, \delta y)}{|\delta x|+|\delta y|}\bigg|=\frac{|g(\delta x, \delta y)|}{|\delta x|+|\delta y|}\leq\frac{|g(\delta x, \delta y)|}{\sqrt{(\delta x)^2+(\delta y)^2}}\to0$$
for $(\delta x, \delta y)\to0$ due to $g(\delta x, \delta y)\in o(\sqrt{(\delta x)^2+(\delta y)^2})$.

**The reverse direction**. We have the two terms $\phi(\delta x, \delta y),\ \psi(\delta x, \delta y)$. Then note that
$$\delta x\phi(\delta x, \delta y)+\delta y\psi(\delta x, \delta y)\in o(\sqrt{(\delta x)^2+(\delta y)^2})$$
because
$$\frac{|\delta x\phi(\delta x, \delta y)+\delta y\psi(\delta x, \delta y)|}{\sqrt{(\delta x)^2+(\delta y)^2}}\leq\frac{(|\delta x|+|\delta y|)(|\phi(\delta x, \delta y)|+|\psi(\delta x, \delta y)|)}{\sqrt{(\delta x)^2+(\delta y)^2}}\leq$$
$$\leq2(|\phi(\delta x, \delta y)|+|\psi(\delta x, \delta y)|)\to0$$
for $(\delta x, \delta y)\to0$. So we name
$$g(\delta x,\delta y)=\delta x\phi(\delta x, \delta y)+\delta y\psi(\delta x, \delta y)\in o(\sqrt{(\delta x)^2+(\delta y)^2})$$

Comment: so we can  say $F$ is differentiable by definition of (two error term which i showed in picture) iff $F$ is differentiable by Frechet definition right? And how this two are diffrent from increment thm.!

Comment: Yes, exactly. As i showed, there was no difference for the functions $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: thank you ! Just want to ask u know about this proof or u just tried first time?

Comment: For the first time, but i have done a lot of manipulations with little o functions before, so i know what to do in such situations.